# how to get nextvalue of sequence from oracle_database and show it in JOptionPane in netbeans using oracle 10g?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

the above code is executing i.e. the sequence value is incrementing but since i want to show that sequence no. in JOptionPane by taking that sequence value as string, it is not happening. as soon as i click on button an exception is occurring.

see the image to understand more easily.[screenshot of CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGxQ9.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do not link to screenshots of your code. Paste your code into the question itself, indenting all code lines by 4 spaces. Also, if an exception occurs, show it. Insert the full stacktrace in the question. We are not supposed to guess what the exception is, or where it occurred, so also show which line is causing the exception (stacktrace line numbers are useless since you're not going to post the entire file, just the failing code segment.

Answer (score 0):

You call `rs.getString()` before you call `rs.next()`. Can't do that.

Without a `next()` call, there is no "current" row for `getString()` to retrieve values from.

Besides, **why** are you executing the query twice?

Comment: please ignore the second call of rs query and help me with the code. please.

Comment: actually i want to fetch the sequence number then convert it into string so that i can concatenate "missing" with that sequence number and then store it in the database in the form of string.     Please help

Comment: @puneetjain I must be misunderstanding you, because it sounds like you are asking how to convert an integer value (e.g. `123`), and combine that with a string to get a string result (e.g. `"123 missing"`). If that is truly the case, then I'd suggest you go back to your Java beginners manual and read about string concatenation.